# serve .ics file to webcal:// instead of download by browser

Tags: javascript, icalendar

I have some code that is using ics.js framework which uses fileSaver.js (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to create and save a calendar invite (.ics) into the users browser.

Through testing/research I have learned that mobile browsers do not like downloading a file via this javascript download mechanism, and try to render them as text files in the browser instead of trigger iOS/Android to open the calendar program like desktop does.

I was told the way to get these files to open on mobile is to present them to the browser as a "webcal://" link, pointing to my .ics file.

So how do I hijack the download function of fileSaver.js, and force the browser to load that .ics blob/file via "webcal://myInvite.ics" to trigger the calendar app to recognize the file on mobile?

Tried using the URL saving method from FileSaver.js but it does not work :(

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#saving-urls

I also made sure the MIME type was being set.

```js
ics.js

        /**
         * Download calendar using the saveAs function from filesave.js
         * @param  {string} filename Filename
         * @param  {string} ext      Extention
         */
        'download': function (filename, ext) {
            if (calendarEvents.length < 1) {
                return false;
            }

            ext = (typeof ext !== 'undefined') ? ext : '.ics';
            filename = (typeof filename !== 'undefined') ? filename : 'webcal://calendar';
            var calendar = calendarStart + SEPARATOR + calendarEvents.join(SEPARATOR) + calendarEnd;

            var blob;
            if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 10') === -1) { // chrome or firefox
                blob = new Blob([calendar]);
                blob = new Blob([calendar], { type: 'text/calendar;charset=' + document.characterSet });
            } else { // ie
                var bb = new BlobBuilder();
                bb.append(calendar);
                blob = bb.getBlob('text/x-vCalendar;charset=' + document.characterSet);
            }
            
            saveAs("webcal://", filename + ext);
           // saveAs(blob, filename + ext);
           
            return calendar;
        },
```

```js
myApp.js

////////////////////////////////////////////
// ics generator
///////////////////////////////////////////
const calForm = document.querySelector('#add-cal-form');

var el = document.getElementById('add-cal-form');
if(el){
    
calForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    var cal = ics();
    cal.addEvent('Demo Event', 'This is an all day event', 'Nome, AK', '8/7/2019', '8/7/2019');
    cal.addEvent('Demo Event', 'This is thirty minute event', 'Nome, AK', '8/7/2019 5:30 pm', '8/7/2019 6:00 pm');

    cal.download();
});

}
```

If I try to save as URL (`saveAs("webcal://", filename + ext);`) I get this error

```
Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

If I use the default download example (`saveAs(blob, filename + ext);`) then it works fine on desktop spawning the download in the browser. On mobile it will download and render the file as text inside the browser.